# compiling a packaged project dependent on a jar

Tags: java, bash, command-line, jar, package

This seems to me to be a trivial question, but I've had a lot of trouble getting an answer.

I've developed a project in eclipse that is dependent on a jar file, which resides in the project's root directory. All my files are in a package "a.b.c" in a src folder. It runs just fine in eclipse. I now want to run this project from the command line. I do this command to compile the project:

> javac -classpath dependency.jar -d ./bin/ ./src/a/b/c/*.java

Everything is compiled into class files and put into the bin/a/b/c folder. Then I do these commands to run the project:

> cd bin
>
> java -cp ../dependency.jar a.b.c.Main

Now I get "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: a/b/c/Main".

So, how do I run a project that is in a package and depends on a jar file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just include the current dir in the classpath as well - i.e. `java -cp ../dependency.jar:. a.b.c.Main`

Answer (score 1):

You also need to specify your compiled files on the classpath, these will contain your `a.b.c.Main`. On *nix flavor machines the path separator for cp is the colon (`:`), and on windows it's a semicolon (`;`), so on *nix, your run command should be (because you're running from the bin directory):

```
java -cp ../dependency.jar:. a.b.c.Main
```